# Not able to render a component while using service in angular2 even though there is no error in the code

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MarketComponent } from './market/market.component';
import { CollectionComponent } from './collection/collection.component';
import{CollectableService} from "./shared/collectable.service";


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
MarketComponent,
CollectionComponent
 ],
     imports: [
BrowserModule,

 ],
 providers: [CollectableService],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

collectable.service.ts

```
 import{Collectable} from "./collectable.model";

 export class CollectableService{
    public collectables:Collectable[]=[
                  {description:'Add a Book',type:'book'},
                  {description:'Add a Mobile',type:'mobile'},
                  {description:'Add a Laptop',type:'laptop'},
                  {description:'Add a Tablet',type:'tab'}
                ];

                  getCollectables()
                  {
                    return this.collectables;
                  }

                }
```

market.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import{CollectableService} from "../shared/collectable.service";

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-market',
   templateUrl: './market.component.html',


   })
  export class MarketComponent implements OnInit {
 collectables=[];
 OnAddCollection()
 {
  alert('Hello');
  }

    constructor(private collectableService:CollectableService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
   this.collectables = this.collectableService.getCollectables();
   }

   }
```

collectable.model.ts

```
  export class Collectable{
  public description:string;
  public type:string;

  constructor(description:string,type:string){
   this.description=description;
   this.type=type;
  }

  }
```

collection.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-collection',
 templateUrl: './collection.component.html',
 styleUrls: []
 })
 export class CollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  }
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

  })
 export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  }
```

When I run this project I am not able to get data from collectable service, from my side I think everything is correct but dont know my data is not getting rendered. I do not get any error messages,still there is no output. Can anybody please see where I am wrong.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watchMz8lb81AAe4&list=PL55RiY5tL51rLeDxRPlE6Hsnss3QDCCKc&index=5         But I am not getting the desired output. If anybody could help me

Comment: I am new to angular2 and followed this tutorial-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz8lb81AAe4&list=PL55RiY5tL51rLeDxRPlE6Hsnss3QDCCKc&index=5  Their is a channel called 'Mindspace' which I am following but I am not getting the desired result. If anybody can please help

Comment: Create a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet- I am not getting your point, Kindly explain it

Comment: You posted a lot of stuff in your question, but yet it's impossible for us to reproduce the problem since there is so many things still missing (the templates, for example). So, create a plunkr that contains all the code and reproduces this problem, so that we can inspect the code, play with it, and try fixing it. http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue, then select New - Angular 2.0.x, and add all the required files.

Comment: @JBNizet- can you please check the 5th video of "Mindspace channel" on youtube containing 7 videos in a playlist about angular2. the link is                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz8lb81AAe4&index=5&list=PL55RiY5tL51rLeDxRPlE6Hsnss3QDCCKc I followed this tutorial to build this project

Comment: Why would I lose my time doing that. I know how to use Angular. I don't need any tutorial. And certainly not one from youtube.

Comment: @JBNizet- If you can send me your email id- I can mail you the entire project. It would be of great help

Comment: No, that's not how it works.